# How to get previous record if current record does not exist in table

Tags: sql-server

my table like this

```
    Id  Date    type    quantity
1   29/04/2019  APPLE   2
2   29/04/2019  Banana  15
3   29/04/2019  Mango   100
4   29/04/2019  Grapes  50
5   29/04/2019  Fish    80
6   30/04/2019  APPLE   4
7   30/04/2019  Grapes  100
8   30/04/2019  Fish    90
9   01/05/2019  APPLE   6
10  01/05/2019  Banana  30
11  01/05/2019  Grapes  150
12  01/05/2019  Fish    100
13  02/05/2019  Mango   200
14  02/05/2019  Grapes  200
15  02/05/2019  Fish    110
16  03/05/2019  APPLE   8
17  03/05/2019  Banana  45
18  03/05/2019  Mango   300
19  04/05/2019  APPLE   10
20  04/05/2019  Grapes  300
21  04/05/2019  Fish    120
22  05/05/2019  APPLE   12
23  05/05/2019  Fish    130
```

i miss some inputs every day,But i need to fill the gaps with previous row of the same "Type" on 30/04/2019 i missed "Banana & Mango"  bu i need like

```
    Id  Date    type    quantity
1   29/04/2019  APPLE   2
2   29/04/2019  Banana  15
3   29/04/2019  Mango   100
4   29/04/2019  Grapes  50
5   29/04/2019  Fish    80
6   30/04/2019  APPLE   4
7   30/04/2019  Grapes  100
8   30/04/2019  Fish    90
9   30/04/2019  Banana  15
10  30/04/2019  Mango   100
```

### actually last two rows are null but it should updated same on 29/04/2019

Comment: There is no row for Mango for `02/01/2019` in your data. Assuming that there *should* be, however, have a look at [LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (you may need to look up `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` as well). Have a go to resolve this yourself and then post your attempt(s) if you didn't succeed. Thanks.

Comment: Note: My above comment changes if you have multiple consecutive `NULL` values for a single value of `input`, however, the answer is quite different (this would turn from wanting to look at the "previous" row to a "gaps and islands" problem). If that is the case, I suggest more sample data and expected results (and don't forget those attempts).

Comment: thanks for reply, yes i have multiple consecutive NULL for single input, I am trying to get the solution but still couldn't achieved

Comment: What were they @Venkat? They aren't in your question. Please do provide us with **representative** sample data and expected results too.

Comment: Every Day some of my in puts (Apple , Banana , Mago) are missing but each day i need the three items for missing row it should updated just previous quantity

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55889595/edit) your question please. Your latest comment implies you might not even have data for a specific date but want data for every fruit. The goal posts are constantly moving here. We need to have a static goal before we can answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiets way might be this:

```
DECLARE @PDate DATE = SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM YourTable ORDER BY Date ASC  --Previous Date
DECLARE @NDate DATE = SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM YourTable WHERE DATE>@PDate  --Next Date

WHILE (@NDate IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

WITH X AS
(
 SELECT T1.Date AS Date1, T1.Type AS Type1, T1.Quantity AS Q1
        T2.Date AS Date2, T2.Type AS Type2, T2.Quantity AS Q2
 FROM YourTable T1
 LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON T1.Type = T2.Type
 WHERE T1.Date = @PDate AND T2.Date = @NDate
)
INSERT INTO YourTable (Date,Type,Quantity)
SELECT @NDate,Type1,Q1
WHERE X.Type2 IS NULL

SET @PDate = @NDate
SET @NDate = NULL  -- If next result wasnt found this stays null for while condition
SET @NDate = SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM YourTable WHERE Date>@PDate

END
```

I think this is the way that may work and I wish so
( if there is any syntax or ... mistakes its because I didnt have SSMS installed to test. Sorry)

Comment: Thanks it is useful for me

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
declare @date date
```

and for initiate `@date` you can use `select @date=max(date) from table1` or pass static value `set @date='02/01/2019'`
and then find `input`

```
select input,max(date) as MaxDate into #temp 
from table1 
where input not in (select input from table1 where date=@date  ) 
group by input
```

then :

```
select t.* from Table1 t join #temp on  Table1.input=#temp.Input and Table1.date=#temp.MaxDate
```

Comment: what is the purpose of "where input not in (select input from table1 where date=@date " )

Answer (score 1):

I think using cursor is a good option to insert your missing entries in the table. By cursor you will be able to check date wise missing types and insert them with the previous quantity.

You can also use this following script to find the missing records in your table. To create the script I consider the table name = 'add_missing_records'

```
SELECT AA.date AS [Date],
AA.type AS [Type],
BB.quantity AS [Original Quantity] ,
CASE 
    WHEN BB.quantity IS NULL THEN 
        ( 
            SELECT quantity 
            FROM add_missing_records C 
            WHERE C.date = (
                SELECT MAX([date]) 
                FROM add_missing_records B 
                WHERE B.date < AA.date 
                AND B.type = AA.type
            )
            AND C.type = AA.type
        ) 
    ELSE BB.quantity 
END AS [New Quantuty]

FROM (
    SELECT date,type
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 'A' AS common,date 
        FROM add_missing_records
    )A
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT 'A' as common, type 
        FROM add_missing_records
    )B
    ON a.common = b.common
) AA
LEFT JOIN add_missing_records BB 
    ON AA.date = BB.date 
    AND AA.type = BB.type
WHERE BB.quantity IS NULL
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: A cursor is the worst option I'm afraid. SQL Server excels at set based methods, not iterative. A cursor is the latter.

Comment: I have added the solution using script. Cursor in not a bad option at all as well :)

Comment: A cursor isn't a bad option when the task needs to be iterative. It is, however, a bad option when something can easily be achieve with a set based operation like this. A cursor isn't like a loop in a programming language. Programs are very good at loops, as that's how they're made. On the other hand SQL Server isn't good at them; it will do each iteration one at a time (not like a program) which is inherently slow. There are certainly times for using a cursors, but this isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after the goal posts are settled, this is one method. Note that this solution builds both a `Types` and `Dates` dataset. Really the `Types` dataset should already exist *somewhere* in your database, and you should create a Calendar Table if you're going to be doing this type of work often.

Any way, I've left comments in the code for you. I've **assumed** you're using SQL Server 2012+, as 2008 is literally about to run out of support.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                          [date] date,
                          [type] varchar(10),
                          Quantity int);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
SELECT CONVERT(date,[date],103),
       RTRIM([Type]),
       Quantity
FROM (VALUES('29/04/2019','APPLE ',2),
            ('29/04/2019','Banana',15),
            ('29/04/2019','Mango ',100),
            ('29/04/2019','Grapes',50),
            ('29/04/2019','Fish  ',80),
            ('30/04/2019','APPLE ',4),
            ('30/04/2019','Grapes',100),
            ('30/04/2019','Fish  ',90),
            ('01/05/2019','APPLE ',6),
            ('01/05/2019','Banana',30),
            ('01/05/2019','Grapes',150),
            ('01/05/2019','Fish  ',100),
            ('02/05/2019','Mango ',200),
            ('02/05/2019','Grapes',200),
            ('02/05/2019','Fish  ',110),
            ('03/05/2019','APPLE ',8),
            ('03/05/2019','Banana',45),
            ('03/05/2019','Mango ',300),
            ('04/05/2019','APPLE ',10),
            ('04/05/2019','Grapes',300),
            ('04/05/2019','Fish  ',120),
            ('05/05/2019','APPLE ',12),
            ('05/05/2019','Fish  ',130)) V([date],[Type],Quantity);

GO
--SELECT *
--FROM dbo.MyTable;
GO
--Create a calendar table
WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 days shuld be enough
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, MIN(MT.[date])) AS [Date]
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS JOIN dbo.MyTable MT
    GROUP BY T.I
    HAVING DATEADD(DAY, T.I, MIN(MT.[date])) <= MAX([Date])),
--Get Types
Types AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Type]
    FROM dbo.MyTable MT),
--Create islands
Grps AS(
    SELECT MT.ID,
           D.[Date],
           T.[Type],
           MT.Quantity,
           COUNT(MT.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY T.[Type] ORDER BY D.[date]
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM Dates D
        CROSS JOIN Types T
        LEFT JOIN dbo.MyTable MT ON D.[Date] = MT.[date]
                                AND T.[type] = MT.[type])
SELECT G.ID AS ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY G.[Date], G.[Type]) AS RN,
       G.[Date],
       G.[Type],
       MAX(G.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY G.[Type], G.Grp) AS Quantity
FROM Grps G
ORDER BY G.[Date],
         G.[Type];

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5516419bc16c818f77cf1af9b63ef4d2)