# Join Data with effective date range

Tags: sql

I have two table;

**Sale Table**; which is a transaction of product sold in each day

| Date | Store | Product | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | A | Apple | 1 |
| 2/1/2021 | A | Apple | 2 |
| 3/1/2021 | A | Apple | 1 |
| 4/1/2021 | A | Apple | 5 |

**Cost Table**; which is the cost of each product containing the effective date

| Product | Effective Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1/1/2021 | 0.5 |
| Banana | 1/1/2021 | 0.7 |
| Apple | 3/1/2021 | 1 |

The cost of the product will be used start from the effective date until the next value announced
This is what I want

| Date | Store | Product | Qty | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | A | Apple | 1 | 0.5 |
| 2/1/2021 | A | Apple | 2 | 0.5 |
| 3/1/2021 | A | Apple | 1 | 1 |
| 5/1/2021 | A | Apple | 1 | 1 |

Can you guys help me with this since I'm very new to SQL. Thank you!!

Comment: Please don't *tag spam*, MySql <> SQL Server <> SQL Lite <> Postgres etc. Please tag the database product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
Select S.Date, S.Store, S.Product, S.Qty, C.Cost
FROM Sale S, Cost C
WHERE S.Product = C.Product AND S.Date = C.EffectiveDate
```

Assuming the name of the Sale Table is "Sale", Cost Table is "Cost"

Comment: It's not that simple since cost of some date is missing. From the table I provide they only give the date that the cost is changed which is 1/1/2021 and 3/1/2021. But if apple was sold on 2/1/2021 the cost of apple must equal to 0.5 but the cost of date 2/1/2021 is missing from the table. How can I join the cost of the apple which sold between the first transaction and the second transaction?

Comment: I have found a similar solution. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889595/how-to-get-previous-record-if-current-record-does-not-exist-in-table/55891444